# Flutter bottom navigation where one page has tabs

Tags: dart, flutter, cross-platform, flutter-layout

I would like to create A scaffold with bottom navigation bar, and an app bar which always displays current page title. When I change bottom bar option, the content changes obviously. Everything this far is ok with classic NavigationBar structure. But the problem starts when on of the content pages should have tabs on top of them. I have my appbar created in parents Scaffold. Is there anyway to add tabs to parent widgets appBar ?

My AppBar + BottomNavBar page:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MainPageState();
  }
}
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {

  int _currentPageIndex;
  List<Widget> _pages = List();

  Widget _getCurrentPage() => _pages[_currentPageIndex];

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      _currentPageIndex = 0;

      _pages.add(BlocProvider(bloc: AgendaBloc(), child: AgendaPage()));
      _pages.add(SpeakersPage());
      _pages.add(MenuPage());
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar( title: 'Agenda'),
      body: _getCurrentPage(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentPageIndex,
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            _currentPageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.content_paste),
            title: Text('Agenda'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.group),
            title: Text('Speakers'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            title: Text('Menu'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now lets say that I want my AgendaPage widget to display tabs on top of view. Is there any easy, non-hacky way to do this ?

Desired effect:
[image: Tabs page]

[image: No Tabs page]

Comment: Using tabs and bottom navigation together sounds like clunky UI. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: I'll edit and add screenshot for some more context.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this, could it be possible for you to place your code solution?

Comment: I don't have access to this code right now. You basically do the stuff in Alexanders answer, and the "_getCurrentPage()" Method returns your widget which should be wrapped in Another Scaffold. But this time this Scaffold can include tabs made in standard way, that can be found in any tutorial. Feel free to ask, if you still have troubles with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use nested `Scaffold` widgets. This works in Flutter 1.1.8:

```dart
// This is the outer Scaffold. No AppBar here
Scaffold(
  // Workaround for https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7036
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false, 
  body: _getCurrentPage(),  // AppBar comes from the Scaffold of the current page 
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    // ...
  )
)
```

Comment: Marking this answer as correct, since this is what I've ended up doing. Seems to be working well. Just incase someone made my mistake: If you build tabs page with StreamBuilder, note that it will always emit null as the first element. This may cause flutter to render your "No data view" (empty Container probably), and then the correct one. The effect is that tabs 'blinks' every time you switch to them.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't , but I managed to solve this problem by adding a separate `AppBar` to each page navigated through the `bottomNavigationBar`:

provide each of your `_pages` with a separate app bar, and remove the main one from your `build` method.

Comment: Thats what I managed to do. Transition from "app-bar-only-page" to another is smooth. However there is an 'ugly' redraw when switching to page with tabs (app bar blinks for a sec). Thought there might be something I can do about it, just dont know yet.

Comment: if you want the app bar to shrink take a look at `sliverAppbar`